# How to put a symbol at a specific point of a plot with Gnuplot

Tags: label, gnuplot

[Here](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.it/2009/05/gnuplot-tricks-many-say-that-it-is.html) is provided an example of line breaking in a plot drawn with Gnuplot.

Using arrows, as suggested in the link above, the results depend by the axis, i.e. I can't handle the angle of the arrow with simplicity. The following figure shows an example of an ugly line breaking obtained by the example in the link above. 
[image]

To obtain that ugly arrows, I did something like:

```
x1 = 32
yb = 0
yt = 100
tiny=2
set arrow 1 from x1-tiny, yb-tiny to x1+tiny, yb+tiny nohead
set arrow 2 from x1-tiny, yt-tiny to x1+tiny, yt+tiny nohead
```

for the first plot and:

```
x2 = 33
set arrow 1 from x2-tiny, yb-tiny to x2+tiny, yb+tiny nohead
set arrow 2 from x2-tiny, yt-tiny to x2+tiny, yt+tiny nohead
```

for the second.

Hence, instead of using arrows, I wish to use a symbol to be put at the end of the axis. A symbol is in pt and doesn't change with the axis length. I think it should be done by putting a label centered into a specific point.

**Which is the code to do that in Gnuplot?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following lines for the first and the latter plot, respectively:

```
set label "/" at x1, yb center font "Symbol,24"
set label "/" at x1, yt center font "Symbol,24"

set label "/" at x2, yb center font "Symbol,24"
set label "/" at x2, yt center font "Symbol,24"
```

This should work!

Comment: there is a risk here the centered symbol wont exactly hit the desired point.  I'd be inclined to stick with the original approach and work through the math to get the angles right on the log scale.

Comment: @george Please, why don't you post your own answer if you think it could lead to a better solution?

Comment: @george Are you sure that the symbol won't exactly hit the desired point? I did a test and this solution works to me! You approach is very difficult to be tackled, since one need to make tedious calculations every time the "aspect ratio" of the subfigures is changed!

Comment: I guess its unlikely that a slash would fail to go right through the center of the character box.. just paranoid. Anyway I worked up an alternative that I will post as an answer in a bit.

Answer (score 0):

the trick to specifying your arrows at fixed angles is to work in graph coordinates.

(Note my split axis approach does not work right with the postscipt driver..not sure why)

```
set terminal png
set yrange [0:20]
set multiplot
set ytics nomirror
set xrange [0:10]
set border 7  #left,top,bottom
set key left
dy = .025  #height of slash in graph coordinates
dx = dy/tan(10*pi/180)  # 10 degree angle
set arrow nohead lt -1 from graph 1-dx,-dy to graph 1+dx,dy
set origin 0,0
set size .5,.8 
set xtics (0,4,8)
plot sqrt(x)
set origin .5,0
set xrange [100:200]
set border 13 #right,top,bottom
unset ytics
set nokey
unset arrow
set arrow nohead lt -1 from graph -dx,-dy to graph dx,dy 
set xtics (125,150,175,200)
plot sqrt(x)
```

Note this will work just fine if you have log scales..

[image]

oops forgot the top, for that you just do

```
set arrow nohead lt -1 from graph 1-dx,-dy+1 to graph 1+dx,dy+1
```

Comment: But you set the size of the plots to be 50%-50%! Try 80%-20% and then let me know if the arrows are nice or not!

Comment: Ah, i see the trouble. Its not that the calcuation is hard, its that when you set aspect ratio by setting margins its hard to know what the actual ratio is going to be precisely.  (And it depends on the output driver ).  It looks like the latest verision of gnuplot has better margin setting tools, I'll come back to this when I get a chance to upgrade.

Comment: Ok, I'm glad that you understand the problem. The example from which I started the question was nice because of the aspect ratio, but in my case I'm not so lucky! At the moment, the solution by JeanValjean is better and works fine to me!